# Wiring a dual coloured LED by two different sources

Tags: mosfet, wiring, led-strip

I have a 12V dual colour LED strip that I am trying to power from two different power sources on a motorcycle:

1. **Source 1:** Daytime running light (Always on)

   This is constantly ON and always on when the motorcycle is on.
2. **Source 2:** Signal light (intermittent when signals are on).

   This source is only ON (intermittently flashing) when you signal  left/right.

The LED strip has 3 wires:

1. **Black**: positive
2. **Red**: ground for white LEDs
3. **Yellow**: ground for yellow LEDs

[image]

**Questions:**

1. How can I wire the two sources so:

   1. Source 1 (daytime): only lights up the white LED
   2. Source 2 (signals): only lights up the yellow
2. How can I make it so the white LED is off while the yellow is on?

| Source 1 | Source 2 | White LED | Yellow LED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ON | OFF | ON | OFF |
| ON | ON | OFF | ON |

Comment: May I assume, since you mention wanting the white to be off when the yellow is active, that you have already tried to hook this up and noticed the issue?

Comment: How will we know when flashing should start and stop? Tell us more about the sources please, in as much detail as possible.

Comment: I have added more details. Both sources already exist on the motorbike, they are both 12v. Source 1 is constantly ON when the motorbike is ON, Source 2 is when you turn on the turning signals. Source 2 is OFF with zero volts by default. Only when we turn the signals on that it emits 12v.

Comment: If it's not legal to have those lights on your bike, don't make your bike illegal.

Comment: @Justme are they?? which country? I'm in Australia.. I saw some on a BMW and they sell them here https://hposkam.nl/en/product/bmw-led-embleem-knipperlichten-met-runninglights-set-70-mm/ they are not a replacement to the existing signals.. they are in addition.

Comment: Just because someone sells something does not mean they are legal everywhere. Quote from website you linked : "These ... are not approved for use on public roads in some countries and should not be used there!
Please check your local legislation.". It's your responsibility to find out how you are allowed to mod your bike in your country.

Comment: +1 for the truth table but I think you'll need to prevent alternate white / yellow flashing when the turn signal is on. That may require the addition of a delay so that white only turns on after yellow has been off for a second.

Comment: @Transistor you are right.. I have created new question asking for help please https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/670677/how-to-add-delay-to-circuit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving aside legal questions, for a moment...

Since Source1 in your truth table is ON in both positions, the output actually is only controlled by Source2 and we can treat Source1 simply as power. So in this case we can connect Source1 directly to +12V of your LED strip and use Source2 to control yellow/white switching using a relay.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPI1Mm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You might want to add a delay circuit so that when the turn signal is off the white light doesn't come on immediately. (that's what I did on my car) This way the turn signal is more visible as it's signalling Yellow/OFF instead of just changing the color Yellow/White.

Comment: That's excellent! thanks a lot for that @floppydisk .. it works well in the simulator.. will build it up.

Comment: I created a new question needing help with the delay circuit.. need to do the same thing you did to your car.. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/670677/how-to-add-delay-to-circuit