# How to add delay to circuit

Tags: mosfet, capacitor, light

I have [this circuit](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgoqoQFMBaMMAKAHNwNDwwUe-mfKpBYAlCgBYJ-EIXwzhICVV5Q1MBCzCE+mXXjyduKAyD4ATOgDMAhgFcANgBcGDuufDqosVtt0Y+CUMwLiVDC2t7Z1d3LwgYSFYAd0lpQVSzUxEU5SoTQ2w0TMNso2Ky9NKEKXKJQvLSkO4gitURcQQ5MNl5FsVlcCF1aE0AJzMA7uxsZpKzOBYAZwoulqCqPs8nUbs6FislbTMBiSP8kGnwEe9IFBYcvA3DU9moe8PX6deRccK80z0DXmpRe3VBKAGIiAA) where a switch is used to toggle between the blue and red LED.

[image]

[image]

- How can I add a delay so that when an ON switch is tuned OFF the RED LED doesn't turn on immediately
- If the switch is turned on again, during the delay, the Red LED remains off and delay resets.

| Steps | Switch | Red LED | Blue LED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | OFF | ON | OFF |
| 2 | ON | OFF | ON |
| 3 | OFF | OFF + delay | OFF |
| 4 | OFF | ON after delay | OFF |

I saw [this great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RwSga-zQy0I) explaining how to add delays using Zener Diodes but I didn't know how to implement it in my circuit.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be easy with a single transistor, if it weren't for the reset requirement. That will need a second transistor, I think. I'll use another transistor M2 to keep a capacitor, C1, discharged while the switch is closed, but to allow it to charge slowly when open:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnfade.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The first plot below shows the state of the switch, high being closed. The plot below that shows LED currents, D1 (blue LED, blue trace) and D2 (red LED, orange trace):

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the blue LED D1 follows switch state. The red LED D2 comes on a couple of seconds after switch SW1 is released, but turns off immediately when the switch is pressed again (the "reset" you spoke of).

Zener diode D3 (together with R5) raises M1's gate potential to be 4.7V *above* the capacitor's voltage. It then takes much longer for M1's gate to fall in potential far enough to reach its threshold voltage. Transition occurs when capacitor C1 develops about \$\frac{2}{3}\$ of the supply voltage, which means that the delay is approximately \$C_1 \times R_4\$.

Comment: Thanks @simon that works. I will just experiment with the capacitors size to get the timing right.